# Set a breakpoint in another package's R function

Tags: r, debugging

When I'm working on code in my own package, it's easy to set a breakpoint just by clicking in the margin of the editor window.

But suppose I want to know what's going on in somebody else's code, say in `stats::predict.lm()`. I'm concerned with a particular place way down in the code, say at line 75 of that function. I can do `debug(predict.lm)`, then the next time I run the `predict` function, it will bring up the browser at the very beginning of this function, and I have to step through one code line at a time until I finally get to the line in question. Is there a way (perhaps using the `condition` argument of `debug()` that will instead effectively set a breakpoint at line 75 of that function, and save me from having to step through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in the `stats` package are hard, because it's a base package, so you would have to rebuild R with debug information.  Otherwise, it's pretty easy.  Just reinstall the package with debug information (`--with-keep.source` is the option to use), then set the breakpoint using `setBreakpoint()`.

For `stats::predict.lm` with a standard install of R, it's harder because "line 75" of that function is not known to R.  You can set a breakpoint at the 5th statement in the function using

```
trace(stats::predict.lm, at = 5, tracer=quote(browser()))
```

which will result in R breaking around the line

```
type <- match.arg(type)
```

in `stats::predict.lm`.  As @Roland pointed out in a comment, it may be easier to use

```
trace(stats::predict.lm, edit = TRUE)
```

which will let you edit the source of that function to insert a call to `browser()` or any other tracing action.

One oddity:  if you set the tracer using the line above, you will need to call `predict.lm(fit)` directly, rather than calling `predict(fit)` and relying on S3 dispatch to find it.  However, if you use

```
trace(stats:::predict.lm, edit = TRUE)
```

(notice the 3 colons), then you will edit the version in the methods table, and `predict(fit)` will see the tracing, but `predict.lm(fit)` will not.

Comment: `trace(stats::predict.lm, edit = TRUE)` and then add a `browser()` call at (before) the desired line. (Note that you have to call `predict.lm` directly and not via method dispatch.)

Comment: @Roland:  I hadn't noticed that limitation, but the same appears to be true for using `at = 5` or similar.  `trace()` appears to be doing some weird replacements:  if you trace a function, it becomes an S4 object.  Also, `debug()` no longer works on it unless you make the direct call.

Comment: @Roland:  I think the fact that you need the direct call is a bug in `trace()`.  It tries to update the S3 methods table, but it looks in the wrong place and doesn't find it.

Comment: Depending on your confidence in this finding and after ensuring the documentation doesn't say anything about this, you could bring this to the r-devel mailing list.

Comment: I'm not so sure it's a bug now, it might just be a weird design decision.  Using the `:::` version of retrieving the function does allow it to find the S3 table.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's a little disorienting because the line position shown in the window is off by 1 or two ahead of the next line actually run. But it definitely beats stepping through from the beginning.

Comment: @user2554330 Barging in on your exchange, the `:::` thing makes perfect sense to me because `trace(fcn, edit = TRUE)` creates a new copy of `fcn` that is run instead. With the three dots, that definitely refers to a function within the namespace of the package, and so the substitute version steps in whenever that function in that namespace is called. With just `::`, that's something in some export structure somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vscode and create breakpoints. It has an advanced debugger.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: I don't even know what vscode is.